# CFBundleIcons images are too small (smaller than what's displayed on home screen)

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code to return the icon images. It turns out that the icons are too small. I set a breakpoint there, and iconFiles only contains `AppIcon60x60` and `AppIcon76x76`. They are much smaller than the home screen icon displayed.

```
  public static var highResIconImage: UIImage? {
    guard let icons = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleIcons"] as? [String: Any],
      let primaryIcon = icons["CFBundlePrimaryIcon"] as? [String: Any],
      let iconFiles = primaryIcon["CFBundleIconFiles"] as? [String],
      let lastIcon = iconFiles.last,
      let image = UIImage(named: lastIcon)
    else {
      return nil
    }
    
    return image
  }
```

I have also tried appending @2x and @3x, and I did get scaled images, but they are still much more blurry than the icon used in the home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `CFBundleIconFiles`  indeed small.

Tried `CFBundleIconName` and it's much larger image.

```
  public static var highResIconImage: UIImage {
    let icons = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleIcons"] as! [String: Any]
    let primaryIcon = icons["CFBundlePrimaryIcon"] as! [String: Any]
    let iconName = primaryIcon["CFBundleIconName"] as! String
    return UIImage(named: iconName)!
  }
```